# Claim Bitcoin Gold from my paper wallet

Tags: paper-wallet, bitcoin-gold

I have asked similar questions in the past, But I didn't get a clear answer yet. I have my bitcoins in a paper wallet, Everywhere I am reading that exchanges like yobit,hitbtc etc will support bitcoin gold if the bitcoins were in their wallet before the fork happened. Which in my case is still in my paper wallet. So now, to which wallet I should import/transfer so that I can claim bitcoin gold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The blockchain has just forked, but the clients are not ready. They still haven't added replay protection, so the "specs" is not ready  too. When they release the client, you'll be able to import your paper wallet private key and claim your Bitcoin Gold.

Now, just don't fall for "claim your bitcoin gold" scams.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the Bitcoin Gold (BTG) blockchain explorer is up and running now, but when I entered a public address from one of my Bitcoin paper wallets that had Bitcoin on it at the time of the alleged fork/snapshot in October, an error message is coming back effectively stating that not only are there no BTG funds on the wallet, but that there never were any on it. I also attempted to sweep the same paper wallet through the BTG wallet for the Coinomi wallet application, and the exact same error message appeared.

I did remove the actual Bitcoin from my paper wallets following the time of the alleged fork/snapshot for BTG, but the BTG balances - if there were any balances - should show up through the blockchain explorer. I know that with the Bitcoin Cash fork, my BCH coins were all showing up on the separately respective BCH blockchain explorer both before and after I had removed the actual Bitcoin from them.

So my first guess here is that this whole Bitcoin Gold thing is a nice little scam and that there never was any so-called "snapshot" made of any public addresses; and that no BTG was ever allocated to those public addresses. If there had been, then at least a "history" of those funds being on the wallets should show up through the blockchain explorer regardless of whether maybe the funds could have gotten stolen through some alleged "replay attack."

SCAM, SCAM, SCAM, Bitcoin Gold! I'll never think any different at this point...

Comment: Or, it might just be a bit buggy still (or you made an mistake somewhere along the way). Time will tell I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that if you had BTC during the snapshot that the BTG developers took in October you will be able to claim an equivalent amount of BTG using your private key of the address your BTC was in at the time of the snapshot. The Coinomi wallet claims to be able to allow you to do this but we won't know for certain until tomorrow after the BTG chain starts getting publicly added to.